# "More to go" text is incorrect

Tags: discussion, status-completed

When commenting on stackoverflow, there is a required minimum number of characters. Below the comment box is a line of text, telling you how many more characters must be typed, which reads:

> `n` more to go..

where `n` is the number of characters left to reach the minimum. However, I believe that this text should probably read either:

> `n` more to go...

or

> `n` more to go.

The difference being the number of periods, either making an ellipsis or a full stop.

Comment: If anything I think it should be `...` or no periods at all.  A full stop there doesn't make sense as it is not a complete sentence, but a fragment.  But it definitely should not just be `..`.

Comment: I hope that the devs mark this as ASAP, Code Red, DEFCON 1

Comment: Dear Wilduck, I will personally come to your house and bludgeon you to death with a giant dot. — Jeff ([reference](http://twitter.com/#!/codinghorror/status/1165936105)) Hmmm, might not be so effective.

Comment: I propose that, instead of a period or an ellipsis, the comment field be pre-filled with ***BAD** USER, KEEP TYPING*. The user has to type 15 characters before this text disappears.

Comment: Oh no. I dearly hope that Jeff doesn't personally look at every question tagged as a "bug." That would be rather embarrassing..

Comment: Someone on the SE dev team does look at every question that is tagged [bug].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I changed it from

> ..

to

> ...

I was going to use `&hellip;` aka … but the JavaScript there is calling `.text` not `.html` so...

Comment: -1 for being completely sensible

Comment: +1 for being completely sensible :D

Answer (score 9):

Or as you type the periods disappear

```
a               - 14 more to go..............
ab              - 13 more to go.............
abc             - 12 more to go............
abcd            - 11 more to go...........
abcde           - 10 more to go..........
abcdef          -  9 more to go.........
abcdefg         -  8 more to go........
abcdefgh        -  7 more to go.......
abcdefghi       -  6 more to go......  
abcdefghij      -  5 more to go.....  
abcdefghijk     -  4 more to go....  
abcdefghijkl    -  3 more to go...  
abcdefghijklm   -  2 more to go..  
abcdefghijklmn  -  1 more to go.  
acbdefghijklmno - 585 characters left
```

Answer (score 9):

How about a more direct message:

```
a               - KEEP TYPING! 14  ಠ_ಠ つ  ◔◡◔
ab              - KEEP TYPING! 13  ಠ_ಠ -╮ ◔◡◔
abc             - KEEP TYPING! 12  ಠ_ಠ -⌢◟ ◔◡◔
abcd            - KEEP TYPING! 11  ಠ_ಠ --​⌢ ๏◡๏
abcde           - KEEP TYPING! 10  ಠ_ಠ -⌣◜ ๏◡๏
abcdef          - KEEP TYPING!  9  ಠ_ಠ ◞◜⁀ ๏_๏
abcdefg         - KEEP TYPING!  8  ಠ_ಠ ◞◜ঌ ๏_๏
abcdefgh        - KEEP TYPING!  7  ಠ_ಠ ◞◠◟ ๏_๏
abcdefghi       - KEEP TYPING!  6  ಠ_ಠ ◞◠⌣​ ⊙_⊙
abcdefghij      - KEEP TYPING!  5  ಠ_ಠ ◞⌢⌣​ ⊙_⊙
abcdefghijk     - KEEP TYPING!  4  ಠ_ಠ ◞-⌣​ ⊙_⊙
abcdefghijkl    - KEEP TYPING!  3  ಠ_ಠ --​⌢ ⊙_⊙
abcdefghijklm   - KEEP TYPING!  2  ಠ_ಠ -╮  ಥ_ಥ
abcdefghijklmn  - KEEP TYPING!  1  ಥ_ಥ つ   ಥ_ಥ
acbdefghijklmno - 585 characters left..
```

Comment: +1 for having two dots .. at the end